# How to make set state value only when axios response is different from previous response

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-state

How to make set state value only when Axios response is different from the previous response

My code

```
    function App() {
  const [Data, setData]=useState(0)
  const prevValue = usePrevious(Data)
  // const prevValues = usePrevious(window.userInput);
  useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/get').then(resp => {
          setData(resp.data[0])
          // prevValue.current- = resp.data[0];
          });
         window.userInput()
            },[Data]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <Home data={Data}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash, you can use [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54473581/7332807) here I believe. (Performance will degrade with scale, however)

It appears you `resp.data` is an array, so with this assumption we can create a new array with the difference between the two.

- If you only want a boolean, you can check if the length of that array is greater then zero, using `.length()`.
- If you want to have the difference as the new state, the output of `difference` can be set as the new state.
- If you instead want to simply want to combine the data, then you should see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54473581/7332807), as your use of Promises (then()), will allow you to do so

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you explain?

Comment: I want to trigger a function when axios reponses value changes. But when i call it directly it executes in every second as axios works but i am unable to compare i want on value changes to trigger that function